# resetable form with url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working in a html "form" with selectable values. I would like that when i select a value the page load an URL, and in the same time i would the reset of the form (select the default value, the one that has the code selected="selected").

I can obtain the two results separately. If i try to make these work together the page load only one function (in the desktop browsers work, but i need that they work in the mobile)

I need because if a user, after the selection of a value, decides to turn back at the previous page, will find the value selected, and he can't select it again

I show you the codes, one with jquery and another without:

/////////////////////////////////////////////////// jquery

```
<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.min1.7.2.js'></script>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
$(function(){
// bind change event to select
$('#titolo').on('change', function () {
var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
if (url) { // require a URL
this.selectedIndex = 0;
window.location = url; // redirect
}
return false;
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="contatto" id="contatto">
<SELECT name="titolo" size="1" id="titolo" style="WIDTH: 441px" LANGUAGE="javascript">
<OPTION selected="selected"></OPTION>
<OPTION value="www.ciao.it">01</OPTION>
<OPTION value="www.ciao1.it">02</OPTION>
<OPTION value="www.ciao2.it">>03</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</form>

</body>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// without

```
<head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function resetcampi() {
document.forms['contatto'].titolo.selectedIndex = 0;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="contatto" id="contatto">
<SELECT name="titolo" size="1" id="titolo" style="WIDTH: 441px" LANGUAGE="javascript"
onchange="location.href=contatto.titolo.value; resetcampi()">
<OPTION selected="selected"></OPTION>
<OPTION value="www.ciao.it">01</OPTION>
<OPTION value="www.ciao1.it">02</OPTION>
<OPTION value="www.ciao2.it">>03</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</form>

</body>
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Some helps???

Comment: Even though you reset your form some browsers keep the values in cache so it will still be selected. If I were you I'd reset the form when you enter the page.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers store the form data in their cache and they will auto-fill the form with the last data. So if I were you I'd reset the form on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      //Reset the form when you load the page
      resetForm();

      //Go to the selected URL when the user selects a url
      $('#titolo').change(function() {
         var url = $(this).val();
         if (url.length > 0) {
            window.location = url;
         }
      });
   });

   function resetForm() {
      $('#contatto').each(function() {
         this.reset();
      });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: the problem isn't the browser cache. The problem is that the page can't reset the form fast, before the loading of the url. And if clear the form, doesn't load the url

Comment: when i turn back to the previous page in my mobile, the page doesn't reload

Comment: Then you should take the url and store it in a variable. Clear the form and then redirect to the url you stored. But the problem is that some browsers are storing the formdata. Had this issue before and for instance some versions of IE were still showing the formdata after I cleared the form before redirecting. Doesn't make sense. But the only solution is to clear it when the page is loaded. Give it a try. I have spent hours on this issue before.